# Change Django-Mezzanine-Cartridge From - email after placing order

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, cartridge

In Mezzanine I am using cartridge and I want to change the From email when the shipping details are mailed to the user. The default one is `do_not_reply@WINCTRL-4UBSUNC`. Where can i change this?
Also I want to mail the admin about the order details where can I do this or how do I use post_save() on Order model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `SHOP_ORDER_FROM_EMAIL` in the settings.py

```
SHOP_ORDER_FROM_EMAIL = 'fromemail@example.com'
```

You can check detailed settings about cartridge at http://cartridge.jupo.org/configuration.html

And for BCC to admin add `SHOP_ORDER_EMAIL_BCC` in settings.py like below,

```
SHOP_ORDER_EMAIL_BCC = 'admin@example.com'
```